# Crear dos jugadores para programa de extraer números

Tags: javascript, jquery

El programa trata de ir extrayendo uno a uno los valores de un array de manera aleatoria. Cuando se encuentran dos valores iguales el programa para y nos dice cuantos valores se han extraído en total hasta que se han repetido.

Quiero añadir un jugador, de manera que cuando el programa se realice se ejecute otra vez, que no siga desde la ultima posición si no que vuelva a empezar para poder comparar cual de los dos ha hecho menos extracciones hasta encontrar el número repetido. En el código que adjunto continua el segundo jugador desde donde deja la extracción el primero y no vuelve a empezar.

```js
start = false;
    
function empiezajuego(){
if(!start){
  var name1 = document.getElementById("player1_start").value;
  var name2 = document.getElementById("player2_start").value;
  var aux = true;
        
            if(name1 == "" || name2 == ""){
            alert("Uno de los jugadores no ingreso su nombre");
            aux = false;
            }
            
            if(name1 == name2){
            alert("Los nombres de los jugadores coinciden");
            aux = false
            }
            
            if(aux){ 
            start=true;
            document.getElementById("start_form").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("game_main").style.display = "inline";
            
            document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML=name1;
    document.getElementById("player2").innerHTML=name2;
           
            
            alert("Juego iniciado!! suerte ;)");
            }
        }
        else{
        alert("Juego ya iniciado"); 
        }
    }
    
var cards = new Array(
new Array("bastos", 1), new Array("bastos", 2), new Array("bastos", 3), new 
Array("bastos", 4), new Array("bastos", 5), new Array("bastos", 6), new 
Array("bastos", 7), new Array("bastos", 8), new Array("bastos", 9), new 
Array("bastos", 10), new Array("espadas", 1), new Array("espadas", 2), new 
Array("espadas", 3), new Array("espadas", 4), new Array("espadas", 5),
new Array("espadas", 6), new Array("espadas", 7), new Array("espadas", 8), 
new Array("espadas", 9), new Array("espadas", 10),
);

var cards_views_ids = Array();
var conteo = 0;

function random_card(num){
if(cards.length >0 ){
   conteo++;

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
    var palos = "<br>Palo: "+cards[rand][0]+"<br><br> Valor:";
    var numero = cards[rand][1];
    document.getElementById("div"+num).innerHTML += palos;
    document.getElementById("div"+num).innerHTML += numero;
    
    cards_views_ids.push(numero);
    
    var repetido = 0;
    
    cards_views_ids.forEach(function(dato){
        if (dato == numero){
            repetido++;
        }
    });
     
    if(repetido == 2){
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        
        setTimeout(function(){
   var jugador = document.getElementById("player"+num+"_result");
   if (jugador.innerHTML == "0"){
           var puntua ='Se repitió el valor <br> Palo: ' + cards[rand][0] + ' - Valor: ' + cards[rand][1] +'. Se extrayeron ' + conteo + ' valores hasta encontrar el valor repetido.';
     jugador.innerHTML=puntua;
    } 
        }, 100);
    }
}

}
```

```html
<div id="start_form">
    Jugador 1: <input type="text" id="player1_start"><br/>
    Jugador 2: <input type="text" id="player2_start"><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="empiezajuego();" />
</div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="game_main"  style="display:none;">

<div id="boton"><button onclick="random_card(1);">Extraer</button>
<span id="player1">0</span></div><span id="player1_result">0</span>
<div id="boton2"><button onclick="random_card(2);">Extraer</button>
<span id="player2">0</span></div><span id="player2_result">0</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que agregar variables para el segundo jugador asi:

```js
start = false;
    
function empiezajuego(){
if(!start){
  var name1 = document.getElementById("player1_start").value;
  var name2 = document.getElementById("player2_start").value;
  var aux = true;
        
            if(name1 == "" || name2 == ""){
            alert("Uno de los jugadores no ingreso su nombre");
            aux = false;
            }
            
            if(name1 == name2){
            alert("Los nombres de los jugadores coinciden");
            aux = false
            }
            
            if(aux){ 
            start=true;
            document.getElementById("start_form").style.display = "none";
              document.getElementById("game_main").style.display = "inline";
            
            document.getElementById("player1").innerHTML=name1;
    document.getElementById("player2").innerHTML=name2;
           
            
            alert("Juego iniciado!! suerte ;)");
            }
        }
        else{
        alert("Juego ya iniciado"); 
        }
    }
    
var cards = new Array(
new Array("bastos", 1), new Array("bastos", 2), new Array("bastos", 3), new 
Array("bastos", 4), new Array("bastos", 5), new Array("bastos", 6), new 
Array("bastos", 7), new Array("bastos", 8), new Array("bastos", 9), new 
Array("bastos", 10), new Array("espadas", 1), new Array("espadas", 2), new 
Array("espadas", 3), new Array("espadas", 4), new Array("espadas", 5),
new Array("espadas", 6), new Array("espadas", 7), new Array("espadas", 8), 
new Array("espadas", 9), new Array("espadas", 10),
);

var cards_views_ids1 = Array();
var cards_views_ids2 = Array();
var conteo = 0;
var conteo1 = 0;
var conteo2 = 0;

function random_card(num){
if(cards.length >0 ){
   var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*cards.length);
    var palos = "<br>Palo: "+cards[rand][0]+"<br><br> Valor:";
    var numero = cards[rand][1];
    document.getElementById("div"+num).innerHTML += palos;
    document.getElementById("div"+num).innerHTML += numero;
    
    var repetido = 0;
    
   switch(num) {
    case 1:
     conteo1++;
     conteo = conteo1;
     cards_views_ids1.push(numero);     

      cards_views_ids1.forEach(function(dato){
          if (dato == numero){
              repetido++;
          }
      });
     break;
    case 2:
     conteo2++;
     conteo = conteo2;
     cards_views_ids2.push(numero);
          
      cards_views_ids2.forEach(function(dato){
          if (dato == numero){
              repetido++;
          }
      });
     break;
    }    
     
    if(repetido == 2){
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        
        setTimeout(function(){
   var jugador = document.getElementById("player"+num+"_result");
   if (jugador.innerHTML == "0"){
           var puntua ='Se repitió el valor <br> Palo: ' + cards[rand][0] + ' - Valor: ' + cards[rand][1] +'. Se extrayeron ' + conteo + ' valores hasta encontrar el valor repetido.';
     jugador.innerHTML=puntua;
    } 
        }, 100);
    }
}

}
```

```html
<div id="start_form">
    Jugador 1: <input type="text" id="player1_start"><br/>
    Jugador 2: <input type="text" id="player2_start"><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="empiezajuego();" />
</div>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="game_main"  style="display:none;">

<div id="boton"><button onclick="random_card(1);">Extraer</button>
<span id="player1">0</span></div><span id="player1_result">0</span>
<div id="boton2"><button onclick="random_card(2);">Extraer</button>
<span id="player2">0</span></div><span id="player2_result">0</span>
```

Comment: Hola Alan muchas gracias! es lo que necesitaba! para redondear.... sabes que hay que hacer para que el segundo boton quede disabled como el primero cuando se consigue la repeticion? No se porque uno funciona y el otro no.. Gracias!!

Comment: Podrias agregar un 1 al id del primer boton y seleccionarlo por Id en lugar de TagName como hiciste con los otros elementos

Comment: Vale!! muchas gracias de nuevo Alan!!

Comment: De nada Belinda.

Comment: Hola @alanfcm ojalá veas el mensaje (soy Belinda), resulta que me he dado cuenta que al añadir los dos jugadores los palos se repiten (antes no), es decir, pueden salir dos veces por ejemplo bastos 4 y por lo tanto lo cuenta como que se ha repetido el valor, pero no deberían repetirse los palos, o sea, no debería repetirse ningún valor del array. Tiene algún problema el Math.floor? Mil gracias de verdad!

Comment: Necesitas otra variable para guardar el palo y tambien comparar tanto el palo como el numero.  Si los dos son repetidos, entonces desabilitarias el boton

Comment: hola @alanfcm coloqué cards.splice(rand, 1); y parece que no se repite, como lo ves? lo que no me queda claro es si el segundo botón vuelve a coger todos los elementos del array o continua por donde lo dejó el primer botón, que opinas? Gracias!

Comment: Creo que splice funciona bien.  En mi respuesta los dos botones son individuales, por eso las dos variables.

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias por todo @alanfcm !!